# Django custon form with validate

Tags: django, forms, model

I have some problem with the form and Django.
I would like to do a custom (in column and with style) form from a model. But after few hours to try I thinks it's not possible.
So I decide to create not a forms.ModelForm but a forms.Form, in order to custom my form. But in this way  i can't keep the validations...
And last thing I try, it in the template file to write a validation manually, it's work but when I submit my form with error, and when it's refresh, all the data are loose, and I see just the error message...
So it make me crazy... I just would like to do a nice form with django...
Thanks in advance

forms.py

```
class PatienceForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Patience
    fields = ('nom', 'prenom', 'age', 'email')
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
{% csrf_token %}
      <p><label for="id_nom">Nom :</label> <input type="text" name="nom" maxlength="200" required id="id_nom"></p>
<p><label for="id_prenom">Prenom :</label> <input type="text" name="prenom" maxlength="200" required id="id_prenom"></p>
 <p><label for="id_age">Age :</label> <input type="number" name="age" required id="id_age"></p>
 <p><label for="id_email">Email :</label> <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" required id="id_email"></p>
{% for err in form.email.errors %}
 {{err}}
{% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

view.py

```
def post_essaie(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PatienceForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        logging.info('Hello')
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return render(request, 'blog/succes.html')
    return render(request, 'blog/teste.html', {'form': form})
else:
    form = PatienceForm()
return render(request, 'blog/teste.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: So, from what I understand, you want to style your forms, right?

Comment: Yes it's exact !

Answer (score 0):

for your form.py :

```
class PatienceForm(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField(max_length=200,label='Nom')
    prenom = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = forms.integerField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
    
# use clean to verify your form
    def clean(self): 
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        nom = cleaned_data.get('nom')
        prenom = cleaned_data.get('prenom')
        age = cleaned_data.get('age')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        if not name and not email and not message:
            raise forms.ValidationError('le formulaire est vide')
```

in your views.py you can use :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm

def post_essaie(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatienceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            logging.info('Hello')
            nom = form.cleaned_data['nom']
            prenom = form.cleaned_data['prenom']
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            # here create your entry with all the data from your form then add  
            # your published_date
            post = Patience(nom=nom, prenom=prenom, age=age,
                            email=email, published_date = timezone.now())

            post.save()
            return render(request, 'blog/succes.html')
    else:
        form = PatienceForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/teste.html', {'form': form})
```

Voila Bonne journée !!

Comment: It's not work. When i try to write a bad email it's considered like valid with no message.